# WSO2 API with WSO2 IS as KeyManager - NPE when using OAuth authorization

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Having WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0 and WSO2 IS 5.3.0 KM (with prepackaged Key Manager) I set up the Key Manager as [described in the documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager).

The main intention is authenticate and authorize users with other federated IdPs and add some authorization capabilities.  My assumption is that users auhorized with WSO2IS will receive an OAuth token valid for the defined APP and API.

So far all on localhost with IS offset 1. I created an API, an application and that is usable from the API Store.

When trying to authorize a client through WSO2 IS using the code grant_type authorization:

```
https://localhost:9444/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=KJTbkbFmcDvslo2fjhzfQkaBH3Ea&redirect_uri=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/test2/callback
```

I am asked for credentials and authorization grant (looks ok) and then I receive an exception on IS:

```
[2018-03-27 10:43:51,822] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [OAuth2Endpoints] in context with path [/oauth2] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
...
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.authorize(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:251)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.sendRequestToFramework(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:1163)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.authorize(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:135)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.authorizePost(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:574)
```

What I assume I misconfigured some endpoint, however - any idea which service is invoked by the  OAuth2AuthzEndpoint implementation or potential cause for this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already reported in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5581.

You can WUM update the WSO2 IS 5.3.0 to resolve the issue.

Comment: Oh, I see, once the client gets the subscription, it could be 'wummed' . Until then I will have to rebuild the library :)